# Probability of at least 1 out of 4 televisions breaking?

Tags: statistics

If a television has an 8% chance of breaking in its lifetime, and I buy 4, what are the chances of at least 1 breaking in its lifetime?

If I only had 2 I suppose I would do: P(A) + P(B) - P(AB).

But I have 4.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the event "at least $1$ breaking" is the complement of the event "none break," so the probability that some TV breaks is just $1$ minus the probability that none break.

Now to find the probability that none break, note that each TV has a $92\%$ chance of not breaking. Thus the chance that all four survive is

$$(0.92)^4$$

and the probability we want to find is

$$1 - (0.92)^4$$

Answer (score 0):

The probability of a television not breaking is 92%. The probability of 4 TVs each independently not breaking is $.92^4=.716$. The probability that all four don't break is $1-0.716=0.284$. So approximately, there is a 28.4% probability that at least one will break.

Comment: The third sentence should be revised?